# Why are my Values from a database not displaying in my drop down menu ?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pg

I've coded this page in a combination of html5 and PHP per its' specifications. My problem is that when I connect the page to a specific database (which I do twice on this page) the second connection displays the values in the table I laid out flawlessly, but the first connection gives me a drop down menu with empty spaces. The menu is suppose to display all 50 states in alphabetical order as they do in my table below it. The empty spaces in the menu seem to equal up to 50 states I just don't have any text displayed in those fields. What am I missing ? I've tried several different ways per other questions on this site, but end up with the same result.

Below is part of the HTML and PHP:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>

<!-- Drop Down set up for Database -->
<select name = "state">
<option value ="default">Select a State</option>

<!-- Retrieve Data from Database -->
<?php
 $db=pg_connect("dbname=etc..");
 $query = "select state_name";
 $query .= " from state_t";
 $query .= " order by state_name";
 $dbResult = pg_query($query);

 if (!$dbResult)
 {
  die("Database error...");
 }

 $num = pg_num_rows($dbResult);
 if ($num == 0)
 {
  echo '<tr><td colspan="2">';
  echo 'Database Query Retrieved Nothing!</td></tr>';
 }
  while ($num = pg_fetch_array($dbResult))
 {
  $state_name = pg_Result($dbResult,'state_name');
  echo '<option value="$num[$state_name]"</option>';
 }
?>
</select>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because syntax error?

Try:

```
while ($num = pg_fetch_array($dbResult))
{
   $state_name = pg_Result($dbResult,'state_name');
   echo '<option value="$num[$state_name]">' . $num[$state_name] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: this way every option will have the same value, the string `$num[$state_name]`

Comment: That's because "$state_name" never changes. You take the value from "$num" by "$state_name". May you could show me your var_dump of $state_name ?

Comment: No, that's because variables and escape sequences are not expanded in strings enclosed between single quotes. You can read more about strings here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Yes, I believe that was one of the ways I used. It still returned a drop down with 50 empty spaces minus the default I applied "Select a State"

Answer (score 0):

The bascic Syntax for select box itself is wrong

The syntax is

```
 <select>
    <option value="a"> A </option>
 <select>
```

Where a = The value you want to get from this option if it is selected,
      A = The value to be displayed to the user

So your coding is supposed to be

```
 while ($fet = pg_fetch_array($dbResult))
 {
      echo "<option value='$fet[state_name]'>".$fet['state_name']."</option>";
 }
```

where state_name is the field name of states in your table

Comment: Yes, I believe that was one of the ways I used. It still returned a drop down with 50 empty spaces minus the default I applied "Select a State".

Comment: I wish I had the reputation to vote your answer because it was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
echo '<option value="$num["$state_name"]" > $num["$state_name"] </option>';
```

instead of:

```
echo '<option value="$num[$state_name]"</option>';
```